# Rails: how to exclude post requests for a before_action in the application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a rails app. I use a before_action in my application controller to get a variable for all identified users (I use it in the header so I need it for all my views).

However, it slows down all my post requests which do not need the variable. I tried to find a way googling it but couldn't find anything. Also, I'm not sure what I am doing is a best practice for the application controller...

How could I exclude all the post requests for this before_action?

One solution would be to copy/paste the code in all my controllers but it seems not the best...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it in many ways. One by using only and except in before action like below
with except:

```
before_action :method_name, except: %I[create update]
```

If you want to skip for any other member or collection routes then you will have to use skip_before_action if your application have many routes then you have to add skip for all controllers.

If you want to skip it for only post requests then you can change your method (before_action method) a bit something like below if you want to exclude all post requests. (bear in mind that it will accept all including put and delete).

```
def method_name
  return if request.post?
  do your stuff
end
```

In other ways we can do one more thing only allow get request.

```
def method_name
  return unless request.get?
  do your stuff
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To stop from calling before_action on post requests

```
before_action :method_name, except: [:create, :update]
```

Comment: I didn't know I could also use this in the application controller! Thanks, it works.